# VMWare ESXi 3.5 "Could not power on VM: No space left on device"

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtualization

We have several VMWare ESXi boxes, and on some we get this message when trying to power on virtuals:

"Could not power on VM: No space left on device
  Failed to power on VM"

The Datastore is 67G, we have two 25G virtuals and 16G free.
the other datastores, also have ~10...20G free

any idea how VMWare handles disk space?

Comment: The stats that your getting from the datastores -- is that from VirtualCenter or are you actually logging into the ESX Server and doing a `df`?

Answer (score 1):

How much memory does the VM you're trying to power on have?

ESX needs to create a swap file the same size of the VM's allocated memory when it's powered on; this swap file is usually create on the same datastore the VM resides in (but this behaviour can be changed).

So, if f.e. the VM has 4 GB virtual RAM, you'll need 4 GB free on the same datastore where the VM is.

If ESX is configured to create the swap file somewhere else, you'll of course need that much space there.

Comment: Datastore=67G

Virtual_1_files=25G
Virtual_2_files=25G

Virtual_1_RAM=2G
Virtual_2_RAM=2G

Virtual_1_Swap=2G
Virtual_2_Swap=2G

* swapfile location = virtual machine directory

it just doesn't add up

Comment: Have you got any snapshots running on those VM's? Also How many vCPU's and are they 32bit or 64bit VM's - Virtualization overhead (memory required for the Hypervisor that also needs to be covered by swap) is higher when you have more vCPU's, and is higher for 64bit machines than 32bit.

Comment: one of the two virtuals has one snapshot, the other one had two but I deleted them from snapshot manager

both are 32bit and both have only 1 cpu

I understand that VMWare will need "some" space for each feature that you mentioned, but do you know how much space? is there such a doc?

thanks!