# Can't start my Windows XP Virtual Machine: Insufficient Disk Space

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hypervisor

Okay, I currently have a server with two virtual machines installed on it, a CentOS5.4 and a Windows XP. I was remote desktopping the Windows XP chatting on IRC, and all of a sudden I lost connection.

I checked with my HyperVisor and tried to restart it, and it won't start at all.

It's giving me this error: Message

> from server0297.serverpool.gnet.ba: 
>   Failed to extend swap file (fileHandle
>   16414)  from 0 KB to 524288 KB: No
>   space left on device.  Could not power
>   on VM : No space left on device. 
>   Failed to power on VM info 4/17/2010
>   9:49:20 PM root

Basically I bought the set up from a host, he installed the HyperVisor and the VirtualMachines, and honestly I don't really know what I'm doing. I've looked at some of the settings, and I can't figure it out. If you need any additional information, I'll try to provide it.

The CentOS5.4 is still starting and working flawlessly, if that's relevant.

Comment: Which hypervisor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VMWare ESXi 3.5 "Could not power on VM: No space left on device"](https://serverfault.com/questions/101728/vmware-esxi-3-5-could-not-power-on-vm-no-space-left-on-device)